# Can I run Java 32 bit and 64 bit in parallel under Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

I want to run two versions of Eclipse. One is only stable (on my machine) under 32 bit the other one only under 64 bit.

Any experience?

Comment: beauty of java. yes you can.make sure you set your java_home/classpath/path vars accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works perfectly. You can install several JDKs and JREs and define in the `eclipse.ini`, which one to use per installation.

Comment: +1 - Using the `eclipse.ini` is better than relying on the PATHs

Comment: tried it and it works! just keep in mind to install both java version in different directories (this is also true for JRE)

Comment: You can also run Eclipse with 64 bit but create separate Run Configurations for 32 by setting a custom JRE / JDK.